# Why would this cause a "#VALUE" error in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: excel, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

DailyLog.o3 through DailyLog.o55 all happen to have the value of 0 in them currently.

This formula in WeeklyLog.f3 works just fine and returns 0:

```
=IF(DailyLog.O3:DailyLog.O9 > 0, AVERAGE(DailyLog.O3:DailyLog.O9), 0)
```

This formula in WeeklyLog.f4 gives a #VALUE error:

```
=IF(DailyLog.O10:DailyLog.O16 > 0, AVERAGE(DailyLog.O10:DailyLog.O16), 0)
```

Just as a test, I entered 1 through 14 in cells DailyLog.o3 through DailyLog.o16. Now WeeklyLog.f3 returns "4" and WeeklyLog.f4 is still returning "#Value"

I simplified WeeklyLog.f4 and it still returns "#VALUE"

```
=DailyLog.o10:DailyLog.016
```

I also tried adding the formula to WeeklyLog.f5 through WeeklyLog.F8 with their appropriate ranges and all of those show "#VALUE"

Now I changed WeeklyLog.f3 and it shows "17.5":

```
=IF(DailyLog.O3:DailyLog.O16 > 0, AVERAGE(DailyLog.O3:DailyLog.O16), 0)
```

Comment: Did you enter it in as an array formula by using Ctrl-Shift-Enter?

Comment: Ctrl-Shift-Enter doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: You need to do it when in Edit mode.  Select the cell click in the formula bar.  Then hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Comment: Doing that just makes the cell equal "Err:520" ... it doesn't even let me enter the formula.

Comment: Apparently the formula needs to be located between WeeklyLog.F10 and WeeklyLog.F16 because those are the rows used in the formula.  Strange behavior -- maybe a bug.

Comment: Actually, the o3:o16 formula works in any of the f column. It's got to be a bug in Calc.

Comment: O3:O16 does not work for me in F2.  It works in F3 through F16.

Comment: In excel the order would be `AVERAGE(IF(DailyLog.O10:DailyLog.O16 > 0,DailyLog.O10:DailyLog.O16))` entered with Ctrl-Shift-Enter  Try that.

Comment: @ScottCraner: Yes, using an array formula in LibreOffice fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a bug, but to me it looks like a bad idea to use a range without an array formula or a function expecting a range.

Here is an alternative that does not require an array formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(DailyLog.O10:DailyLog.O16, "<=0"), 0, AVERAGE(DailyLog.O10:DailyLog.O16))
```